# Django task not running using crontab

Tags: python-3.x, cron, ubuntu-18.04, django-1.11, django-kronos

I am using `django-kronos` to create a cron job and it is running fine when I run it manually. But it is not running in case of crontab.

Below is my code to test if it is working:

`settings.py`

```
ENV_PATH = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, '.env')

# Adding KRONOS PROPERTIES
KRONOS_PREFIX = '{} '.format(ENV_PATH)
KRONOS_POSTFIX = '>> /var/log/cron.log 2>&1'
```

I have my passwords in `.env` file. Hence I have used `KRONOS_PREFIX` to export those variables first. `KRONOS_POSTFIX` is used to add logs to my cron.

`cron.py`

```
import kronos

@kronos.register('* * * * *')
def test_task():
    print("IT WORKS....")
```

`Commands:`

```
$ python manage.py showtasks

* List of tasks registered in Kronos *
>> Kronos tasks
    >> test_task
>> Django tasks

$ python manage.py installtasks
1 task removed, 1 installed.
```

`crontab -l`

```
* * * * * /home/sam/..../.env  /home/sam/.../venv/bin/python /home/sam/.../manage.py runtask test_task  --settings=my_project.settings >> /var/log/cron.log 2>&1 # kronos:4f383ee5e8844285d6ac6dc78196e377
```

It works when I run the command mentioned in `crontab` manually and logs the output as well. I checked several articles online without any success.

I found this [digitalocean article](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/questions/unable-to-execute-a-python-script-via-crontab-but-can-execute-it-manually-what-gives) somewhat similar but this is also not working in my case.

Any help is much appreciated.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After checking several articles for a few hours and debugging, I found out that the main issue was with the `source .env` i was using. crontab was not able to export the environment variables using that command. So, I decided to create another file with the name `.env_constants` and update `KRONOS_PREFIX` as follows:

`settings.py`

```
KRONOS_PREFIX = 'env - `cat {}` '.format(os.path.join(BASE_DIR, '.env_constants'))
```

`.env_constants`

```
DB_NAME=db_name
DB_USER=db_user
DB_PASSWORD=db_password
DB_HOST=localhost
DB_PORT=port_no
```

And my cron now looks like:

```
* * * * * env - `cat /home/sam/.../.env_constants`  /home/sam/.../venv/bin/python /home/sam/.../manage.py runtask test_task  --settings=my_project.settings >> /var/log/cron.log 2>&1 # kronos:4f383ee5e8844285d6ac6dc78196e377
```

Now it is running fine.